# remove NA's from only one Variable in scatter plot with 2 variables over time in R / ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, na

I want to plot 2 variables over a time period with ggplot. One of the variables contains NAs. I want to drop the NAs from the plot without losing the value for the other variable. Right now, ggplot plots all NAs in a line at the top of the y-axis.

I tried using the filter function, but ggplot complains since the rows don't match up:

```
cov_vs_no_scent_share_plot = cov_vs_no_scent_share %>%
  gather(key,value,no_scent_share , new_cases) %>%
  filter(!is.na(cov_vs_no_scent_share_plot$no_scent_share)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=value, colour=key))
```

The Dataframe is structured like this:

cov_vs_no_scent_share:

```
Date, new_cases, no_scent_share
2019-01-01, 1, 0.5
2019-01-02, 3, NA
2019-01-03, 5, 0.2
2019-01-04, 2, NA
2019-01-05, 1, 0.1
2019-01-06, 9, NA
...
```

I want the x-axis to represent the date and "new cases" and "no_scent_share" on the y-axis.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I have edited the question to make things clearer. I want the date on the x-axis and 2 different variables (new_cases and no_scent_share) on the y-axis. I have added some dummy data. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with a rug plot. In the absence of a reproducible example, let's take the built-in `mtcars` data set.

Suppose we wanted to plot `wt` against `mpg`, but we don't have measurements for `mpg` for any cars with a `wt` greater than 4:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- mtcars[c(6, 1)]
df$mpg[df$wt > 4] <- NA
```

If we want to indicate that we have `wt` for all the cars, but no `mpg` value for some of them, we can add a `geom_rug` along the x axis. This will show us all the values we have for `wt`, even if the data for `mpg` is missing:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_rug(sides = 'b')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply! But thats not quite what I meant: I have edited the question to make things clearer. I want the date on the x-axis and 2 different variables (new_cases and no_scent_share) on the y-axis. I have added some dummy data. thank you!